# MYSQL insert into duplicate key Update with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

*(I just try to learn the duplicate Key Syntax)*

i write an query that should insert Values into a Table but if an entry exists he should update.

```
$reflinkUpdate = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO links (link_first_id, link_linked_id) VALUES (:sid, :tid) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE link_first_id= :sid2, link_linked_id = :tid2');
$reflinkUpdate->bindParam(":sid", $_POST['solo'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$reflinkUpdate->bindParam(":tid", $_POST['reflink'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$reflinkUpdate->bindParam(":sid2", $_POST['solo'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$reflinkUpdate->bindParam(":tid2", $_POST['sel'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

My Code everytime insert entrys and dont Update. What have i do wrong?

Comment: are the fields that you are inserting into have unique indexes on them (or are the primary key for the table) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$reflinkUpdate = $dbh->prepare('
INSERT INTO links (link_first_id, link_linked_id)
VALUES (:sid, :tid)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
  link_first_id = VALUES(link_first_id),
  link_linked_id = VALUES(link_linked_id)
');
```

The `VALUES(field_name)` refers to the value that was trying to be inserted.

Comment: he still insert an entry

Comment: @user3676560 It works only if the duplicate entry is a primary key or unique index.